# TMPro Double Outline

Tags: unity, outline, text-mesh-pro

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

Hi, This is what I am trying to achieve: TextMeshPro with *double outline*.

So far I have tried these combinations:

1. TextMeshPro + Outline[int the mid] + Underlay [external]. It is close, but not the one I am trying to make. The problem in here: The outer shadow `Underlay`'s `Y` offset is limited and can't go down below -1.
   [image]
2. Then I tried to add built-in `Shadow` component but it did nothing.

Is there any way I can achieve this? I don't want to use 2 TextMeshPros. I haven't tried to achieve this in code because I am a super beginner in unity and open to any guidance on that.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I can't help you on this but can you tell me what's the font you used ? Thanks !

Comment: @TakahT Sure mate. The font's name is `CookieRun`. The `black` version is being used in these images.